# Find last data entry point in column I, reference column B and pull data on that same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking for a formula that will search column I for the last data entry input by the user. Then, go to column B and pull the data in the same row as the row that had data entered in it by the user.

Hopefully this isn't too confusing of an explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, your question is too vague for anyone to offer any definitive help. Please read **[ask]**, then edit your question to include more details and a specific question so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: I agree with the above, but as a place to start, look at `=VLOOKUP`, it's what I use to get the last entry in a column.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(I:I))*(I:I<>""))))
```

for example:

[image]

This should work whether the last entry in column **I** is a number or text.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly vague, but if I understand correctly, something along these lines may help you on the right track.

`=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I<>""),I:I), B1:C65535, 2, FALSE)`

`LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I<>""),I:I)` is used to get the last non-empty item of data in the column I

`B1:C65535` would need to be adjusted to the range you actually wanted to search

`2` is the column index based on the range above. EG: 1 would return the item in Column B, 2 would return Column C

`FALSE` is specified to expect an exact match, rather than `TRUE` which would be a loose match.

Please update your request and I can edit or delete my answer as required, but I believe this is along the lines of what you're asking.